# Erro ao consumir json utilizando ajax

Tags: ajax, json, wcf

Tenho o seguinte retorno em json:

```
{
    "ConsultarRegistroPorCodigoResult": {
        "Codigo": 2,
        "CodigoSetor": 1,
        "Login": "ednilson1",
        "Nome": "Ednilson",
        "RegistroAtivo": true,
        "Senha": "123456",
        "Tipo": "D"
    }
}
```

Do *webservice* feito em *WCF* estou usando o seguinte codigo:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <input type="text" id="codUser"/>
        <button onclick="ConsUsuario(); return false;">Consulta Usuario</button>
    </div>

      <div><table id="datagrid"></table></div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ConsUsuario(){
        var value = $("#codUser").val();

        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "ServiceRestPub/ServiceUsuario.svc/ConsultarRegistroPorCodigo/" + value,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
          debugger;
          var tabela = $("#datagrid");
                            var rows = "";
                            tabela.find("tbody td").remove();

                            var myData = JSON.parse(result.d);
                            for (var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {
                                var obj = myData[i];
                                alert(obj.descricao);


                                rows += "<tr>";
                                rows += " <td>" + obj.id_usuario + "</td>";
                                rows += " <td>" + obj.nm_usuario + "</td>";
                                rows += " <td>" + obj.ds_login + "</td>";
                                rows += " <td> <input type='checkbox' /> </td>";
                                rows += "</tr>";
                            }

                            // tabela.find("tbody").html(rows);
                tabela.html('<tbody>' + rows + '</tbody>');

            //console.info(result.d);
            }
        });
    }
 </script>
```

Retorna o erro `'Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0'`, pelo que vi o json esta inválido, como "converto" para um json valido?

O erro ocorre na linha `var myData = JSON.parse(result.d)`, segue a mensagem de erro completa:

> (index):1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at
>   position 0
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at Object.success ((index):31)
>       at l (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at T (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.r (jquery.min.js:2)

o retorno da variável *result*:

> Object {ConsultarRegistroPorCodigoResult: Object}

Comment: Em qual linha ocorre o erro? nas rows?

Comment: Coloca o que tá vindo na variável `result` pro pessoal te ajudar melhor...

Comment: editei e acrescentei o que voces sugeriram, obg

Comment: @InteliderSistemas O retorno em json que você colocou é do `result` ou `result.d`? Se for do `result` tire o `.d` do `JSON.parse`.

Comment: se tiro o .d o erro muda `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`, o erro acontece na mesma linha

Comment: Gostaria de ver o obj: result, q parece já estar vindo deserializado.

Comment: var myData = JSON.parse(result.d); para: var myData = JSON.parse(result);

Comment: @Aline se troco para o que vc indicou o erro muda: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu retorno JSON parece estar correto, o que não parece é a maneira que você tratando-o.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "ServiceRestPub/ServiceUsuario.svc/ConsultarRegistroPorCodigo/" + value,
  contentType: "application/json",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(result) {
    debugger;
    var tabela = $("#datagrid");
    var rows = "";
    tabela.find("tbody td").remove();

    var myData = JSON.parse(result.d); // <~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ (1)
    for (var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) { // <~~~~~~~~~~~~~ (2)
      var obj = myData[i];
      alert(obj.descricao); // <~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ (3)


      rows += "<tr>";
      rows += " <td>" + obj.id_usuario + "</td>"; // <~~~~~~~~~ (3)
      rows += " <td>" + obj.nm_usuario + "</td>"; // <~~~~~~~~~ (3)
      rows += " <td>" + obj.ds_login + "</td>"; // <~~~~~~~~~~~ (3)
      rows += " <td> <input type='checkbox' /> </td>";
      rows += "</tr>";
    }

    // tabela.find("tbody").html(rows);
    tabela.html('<tbody>' + rows + '</tbody>');

    //console.info(result.d);
  }
});
```

**Explicações**

1. Não há necessidade de utilizar `JSON.parse` para obter o resultado. Você já especificou para o jQuery que o seu retorno será um JSON em `dataType: "json"` e, desta forma, o jQuery já entrega para você em `result` um objeto JavaScript construído a partir do JSON. Neste caso você estaria tentando fazer o *parse* de um objeto, não uma *string*, gerando o erro. Este `.d` também não faz sentido algum estar ali;
2. No seu caso, `result` será um objeto JavaScript com apenas um atributo. `ConsultarRegistroPorCodigoResult`, que também será um objeto. Neste ponto do código você parece querer iterar sobre `result` como se ele fosse uma lista de objetos. Não produziria nenhum erro sintático, mas o resultado não seria o esperado, pois ao invés de estar iterando sobre uma lista de objetos, você estaria iterando sobre o objeto em si;
3. Nesses pontos você tenta acessar atributos do objeto que não estão definidos no seu JSON. Perceba que o objeto definido em `result.ConsultarRegistroPorCodigoResult` possui apenas os atributos `Codigo`, `CodigoSetor`, `Login`, `Nome`, `RegistroAtivo`, `Senha`, `123456` e `Tipo`. Você tenta utilizar `descricao`, `id_usuario`, `nm_usuario` e `ds_login`. Nenhum deles existe no seu retorno.

Comment: realmente faltou atenção em alguns pontos, fiz as alterações pelo que entendi porem ainda continua o erro e ficou assim:  var tabela = $("#datagrid");
                       var rows = "";
                       tabela.find("tbody td").remove();

                       for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                           var obj = result[i];
                           alert(obj.Login); ele esta dizendo que o objeto esta indefinido do result. Local
i
:
0
obj
:
undefined
result
:
Object
ConsultarRegistroPorCodigoResult
:
Object
__proto__
:
Object
rows
:
""

Comment: Anderson o codigo acima funcionou apenas modificando a forma como obtenho o valor do result, ex.: result.ConsultarRegistroPorCodigoResult.Codig‌​o, e funcionou blz, valeu obrigado pela ajuda e atenção!

Comment: Depois de fazer as mudanças sugeridas por você!